# Use Cookies and Machine Learning to check bot traffic

Tags: python, machine-learning, cookies

I am going to train a Machine Learning model to categorize bot(repetitive and/or using VPN) traffic coming towards my website(advertisement network) or going towards links produced by my website to advertised pages. I will have typical cookie data([data this website shows](http://webkay.robinlinus.com/)) of my visitors as input for categorization. Is there a dataset to help train my model or is there any other way around(also using Machine Learning)?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use machine learning for this? I don't really work with Bot categorization or cookies (I do machine learning) but I would assume they have distinct characteristics from humans (access things in minimal amounts of time, no mouse movement, etc.). You don't need to use machine learning to figure out these distinctions.

Comment: I have to check the bots clicking on links produced by my website leading to the to-be-advertised pages. The link will redirect to the specified page while giving me the cookie data. There is not enough other stuff to characterize them.

Comment: Yes I can use Captcha or other things but I am supposed to be using a Machine Learning model to make it more efficient